# Missing manpages on a Ubuntu LTS 22.04 Server minimal install

Tags: server, 22.04, manpage

I've installed a 22.04 LTS Ubuntu Server as a minimal install and installed the following packages :

```bash
vim man-db manpages dialog bash-completion screen
```

Now when I run `man ls`, ubuntu is asking me to run the `unminimize` command although the man packages are already installed :

```bash
$ dpkg -l | egrep "man-db|manpages"
ii  isc-dhcp-common                       4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1                      amd64        common manpages relevant to all of the isc-dhcp packages
ii  man-db                                2.10.2-1                                amd64        tools for reading manual pages
ii  manpages                              5.10-1ubuntu1                           all          Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
```

And the directory `/usr/share/man/man1` is empty :

```bash
$ ls /usr/share/man/man1
$ man -w ls
This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, including manpages, you can run the 'unminimize'
command. You will still need to ensure the 'man-db' package is installed.
```

and `mandb` outputs :

```bash
$ sudo mandb
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/id...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/id...
...
Processing manual pages under /usr/local/man...
mandb: cant update index cache /var/cache/man/oldlocal/8087: No such file or directory
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
$
```

The strangest thing is this :

```bash
$ ls $(dpkg -L coreutils | grep man1/ls.1)
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz': No such file or directory
```

Found this :

```bash
$ dpkg -S bin/man
man-db: /usr/bin/manpath
local diversion from: /usr/bin/man
local diversion to: /usr/bin/man.REAL
man-db: /usr/bin/man
local diversion from: /usr/bin/man
local diversion to: /usr/bin/man.REAL
man-db: /usr/bin/mandb
man-db: /usr/bin/man-recode
$ head $(which man)
#!/bin/sh
echo "This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are"
echo "not required on a system that users do not log into."
echo ""
echo "To restore this content, including manpages, you can run the 'unminimize'"
echo "command. You will still need to ensure the 'man-db' package is installed."
$ man.REAL -w ls
No manual entry for ls
```

How can this be solved without having to unminimize Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "minimized" Ubuntu makes some rules in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes`, which include excluding `man` and all manpages from being installed. It also switches the `man` binary to be a file that outputs the message you saw about a minimized Ubuntu. You can edit the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes` and comment out the following line:

```
path-exclude=/usr/share/man
```

Then, you can `apt update` and install `man` and `manpages`

Comment: Thanks Esther. I wish I had your answer sooner. I had to look at the `unminimize` script and finally run it anyway. Therefore I lost the content of `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes`. BTW : When you say install `man` and `manpages`, you mean : re-install them, right ?

Comment: Just to make it completely clear, you must rename /usr/bin/man.REAL to /usr/bin/man and follow up with $ sudo mandb -c to index installed (but not all) man pages. For some packages (e.g. efibootmgr) you need to reinstall the package or do something else to make associated man pages properly indexed.

Comment: EXPERIMENTAL – if you run (do so at your own risk) apt-get install --reinstall on all installed packages the man pages for the already installed ones get picked up by mandb. It's weird that mandb fails to index already installed man pages when run manually but triggering it by reinstalling the packages works. This is obviously a terrible solution but if you're just playing around (like I am at the moment) this will get you man pages for all packages installed. Albeit some problems with the system might transpire later on. That being said,  I haven't encountered any yet.